# Have 2 objects act like one

Tags: objects, rigidbody

I have an apple that is thrown into the air and then sliced in half. Because of this, there are two different objects (the halves of the apple). When it is thrown, I want to use a Rigidbody to get more realistic physics. How can I make the two halves act like one object for a certain amount of time?

Comment: I would do the animation of the single apple first and then swap out/in the two halves. You can do this by animating the Rigid Bodies Dynamic toggle and moving anything in and out of view in a single frame.

Comment: If I do that, you will still see the object fly in because of motion blur, which I want to keep on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving both pieces the same origin, and parent one to the other using the "child of" constraint. Animate it's effect off once it needs to fall away from the other piece.

Comment: How would I give the object with the constraint a rigidbody?

Comment: You would give it a rigid body in the physics settings, and set it as "animated" (as opposed to dynamic) and keyframe that off at the same time you take the constraint off. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Ahh, turning off dynamic was what I was missing. Thank you :)

Comment: Yikes, the half without the constraint  is getting "pushed" by the other half and it's doing weird things. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Has the collision shape been set to mesh? (in rigid body settings)

Comment: Yes but even with mesh their is a tiny margin and my objects are perfectly touching to create a seamless look. If I set the margin to 0, it won't work proprely either

Comment: what if you made two apples- one whole one, and one that was cut. The first one flies up into the air, and then you keyframe off it's render visibility at the same time as you keyframe on the visibility of the cut one. The pieces could come apart and it would look right (probably.) Is that at all helpful? :)

Comment: It shouldn't affect your motion blur either.

Comment: Ok, but other fruits are being thrown and the invisible apple still has a rigid body which is interfering with the other fruits. How can I also turn off the collision?

Comment: Try placing each individual fruit setup in a collection and adjusting the rigid body settings to only interact with that collection.

Comment: Wow! I was not aware that you could have collision collections. This works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you achieve what you are looking for!